# Grub terminal instead of Grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have installed Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10, all works well.
But sometimes when I boot my computer, the Grub terminal shows up and I need to type "exit" in order to access to the Grub menu.

Google didn't help me for now
I already tried to reinstall grub2, without success.

I hope you will be able to help me :)

Comment: Does running "sudo update-grub" from a Ubuntu terminal fix your problem?